# network inbound from other subnets refused to server A, Server A can go outbound to internal networks, but not internet

Tags: linux, networking, routing, vlan, subnet

I have a RHEL 6 server with 4 NICs on 192.168.2.[30-33]/24  Set with DHCP reservations via infoblox, I have checked and the MACs all match up.  ifconfig shows /24 for every netmask, and the routing table looks fine.  I can hit anything I want outbound within our networks, but not the internet.  Name resolution works, but it cant reach internet hosts.  I can access the server on all interfaces fine inbound from the same subnet, but cannot even ping it from other subnets.  iptables and ip6tables are off.  Initially only the first NIC, eth0, was setup, but OPs connected the remaining NICs to the switch, and asked me to restart the network services, which started the problem.  I assume they have something wrong on their end, what would be the go to assumption in this case?

Comment: do you have a default gateway set? If so, is it set correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is identical to working servers on same network

Comment: When I restart network services, other NICs are pingable for a moment, until it finished, then they become inaccessible again, which now makes me think it is a server NIC conflict.

Comment: Please delete this entire question.  It was a problem related to the DHCP reservations.